# Using jQuery Scroll to top when clicking a CSS class element

Tags: jquery, css

I have what seems to be a simple issue to solve, but cannot get the proper formatting using classes instead of href

I want to be able to click on a  with a class of .mtimg  so its

When clicked, on any of those items, because there is quite a few inside a parent DIV with an class of "page_menu" I just want to scroll to the top of that DIV.

SO, quick and simple.... click on .mtimg scroll to top of div.page_menu div

my initial thoughts but couldn't get to work with classes instead of href..

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

    var target = $(this.href);

    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kxj4uwg/4/)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Show a fiddle demo with your markup. There are several possible issues here, but we can't say without a proper example. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You should be able to simply replace `'a[href^="#"]'` with `'.page_menu'`.

Comment: Note that the `if` block only runs if the `href` attribute isn't empty.

Comment: You want to scroll to the top of the page or to the top of the div that contains the clicked selector?

Comment: can we see your html mark up?

Comment: I have edited and added my markup, along with @Sake Salverda suggestion below. I simply want when clicked on the class item "mtimg' to scroll to the top of the Parent Div with a class of "page_menu"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know if the 'a' directs parent is 'div.menu_page' I use jQuery's .closest() otherwise you could just use $(this).parent

```
$(function(){
    $(".mtimg").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //var $parent = $(this).parent();
        var $parent = $(this).closest('div.page_menu');

        var topToScrollTo = $parent.offset().top;

        $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: topToScrollTo}, 1000);
    });
});
```

This should to it.

Comment: I have tried your solution, its jus tnot scrolling though. sorry if i am not explaining well. There is a fiddle above in my original post now.

Comment: If you change "jQuery 1.6.4" to "jQuery 1.7.2" in "Framework & Extensions"  (Upper left) it works , I think it is the jQuery version that is the problem here

Comment: You are correct, this does work correctly with 1.7.2 jQuery, thanks for your input Sake! I actually checked and using 1.11.0 works great as that is what is being loaded ultimately. I should have checked that out first. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.mtimg').on('click', function(){
    var $target = $(this).parents('div.page_menu').first();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $target.offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Tried this as well, no luck on my end unless I am missing something in my fiddle above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to scroll to the top of your `page_menu` div every time you click an element that has a `mtimg` class, it could be simplified a lot. See the minimal example below.

**EDIT:**
Modified the example to use OP's provided markup.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mtimg').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.page_menu').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
/*CSS for display purposes*/
.page_menu {
    border:solid 1px red;
    padding:20px;
}

.mtimg {
    padding:4px;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
    margin:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='page_menu'>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
    <div class='mtimg'>Class Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand using an ID, however I am not at liberty to alter/add that to the existing code unfortunately. =/

Comment: Okay, I removed that comment and modified my example to use the markup you provided.